# Вставка текста из буфера обмена в текстовое поле любого другого приложения - Android

Tags: java, android

По кнопке, которая находится поверх всех приложений, я вставляю в буфер "текст":

```
String temp = new String();

layoutView.findViewById(R.id.PasteInEditText).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ClipboardManager clipBoard= (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText("label","ТЕКСТ"));
                temp = clipBoard.getText().toString();
                KudatoTam.setText(temp);
            }
        });
```

Мне надо, чтобы этот текст автоматом вставлялся по нажатии на `PasteInEditText` в зафокусированное поле **ЛЮБОГО** другого приложения.

Т.е. `KudatoTam` это должно быть поле ввода другого приложения.. Смс например.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите, чтобы ваша "Кнопка" добавляла текст в любое указанное вами поле любого приложения. К примеру, если я сделал приложения, в котором есть поля ввода данных, а вы хотите нажать на кнопку и чтобы в любое поле моего приложения указанного вами вставился текст?

Comment: Да, верно. Заранее вписанный "текст" чтобы вставлялся в любые поля любых приложений.

Comment: долгое нажатие в поле другого приложение -> "Вставить"...
по другому нельзя, т.к. у вашего приложения нету доступа к полям других придложений

Comment: Это то я понял, что нет доступа. Просто думал может есть обходные пути... Например запуск clipboard сервиса и выполнение его функций... Вопрос как!?

Comment: Слава богу никак, а иначе была бы куча вирусов и спамеров, которые бы добавляли спам в письма. Для таких вещей нужен ROOT, тогда всё возможно, но если думать логически, то тут всё просто - нужна ссылка на объект, поэтому вопрос другой, как её получить, но как и писал выше, никак без ROOT

Comment: А если не секрет, зачем вам такая конструкция?

Comment: У меня прога с набором нужных готовых текстов, по кнопкам, чтобы не строчить лишний раз и не прибегать к "выделению/копированию/вставки" а чисто вставки. А если бы еще и без этого обойтись было бы неплохо. Нажал и оно уже там. Типо менеджер буфера обмена некий такой.

Comment: Раз "менеджер буфера обмена", то почему бы вам просто не назначить на кнопку копирование текста в буфер обмена, а в нужном месте просто вставить вручную, в любом случае вам пришлось бы жмякать, а так будет быстрее и без "боли" **ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("simple text","Hello, World!");** почитайте подробнее тут http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

Comment: Посмотрите внимательнее мой вопрос

Comment: Прочитал. Ответ - НЕЛЬЗЯ.

Comment: Я о том, что такая кнопка у меня уже есть

Comment: Тогда лучше решения нет, если ROOT не будет выдан

Comment: Если Вы знаете способ/пример решения с ROOT, буду не против:)

Comment: Прям сразу в голову ничего такого путного не лезет, тут сидеть и думать нужно, ну наверное самая первая мысль, это встраивать C код в приложение, парсить память нужной вам прилаги и находить указатель на нужный вам TextView, а как уже будет известен адрес въюхи, то и обратится к ней можно, так же можно ещё через рефлексию что-то помозговать, но это тоже не всё так просто, в общем я считаю, что вам проще будет сделать так, как уже есть, т.к. идея яйца выеденного не стоит, если только вы не пишите вирус :)

Comment: Подожду ответа...

Comment: Я не настоящий андроидщик, но гугль подсказывает, что вы можете написать свою виртуальную клавиатуру, и уже оттуда вставлять свои заготовленные тексты: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android

Comment: ТОЧНО! тема закрыта. Придется переписывать с нуля.